# Opening modal from FlatList Item and pass item data to it using state variable becomes very laggy and sometimes app not responding

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-flatlist, react-modal

Open a modal for each item of the flatlist and pass that particular item data to that modal data using state Variable becomes very laggy and sometimes app not responding,

```
 const [showFeedMoreModal, setShowFeedMoreModal] = useState(false);
 const [sendUserDetails, setSendUserDetails] = useState();
 const openFeedMoreModel = (item) => {
        setSendUserDetails(item)
        setShowFeedMoreModal(true);
    }
    const closeFeedMoreModal = () => {
        setShowFeedMoreModal(false);
    }
```

and for the flatlist item

```
 <TouchableOpacity 
                     disabled={(item.user.userId == user.user.userId) ? true : false}
                        onPress={() => {openFeedMoreModel(item)}}
                    >
                        <Image source={More} resizeMode="contain" style={{ width: width * 0.044, height: width * 0.044, marginLeft: width * 0.13, marginTop: 7, borderRadius: 22 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {showFeedMoreModal == true &&
                        <FeedMoreModal
                            showModal={showFeedMoreModal}
                            showingModal={openFeedMoreModel}
                            onTouchOutside={closeFeedMoreModal}
                            setmodal={setShowFeedMoreModal}
                            title="Create"
                            navigation={props.navigation}
                           
                        />
                    }
```

Please help to overcome this problem ...what should be the solutions?

Comment: Please help i am not getting any answer yet!!!